# Would it be possibile to insert Google Maps Streetview mode in Unity?

Tags: google-maps, unity-game-engine, google-street-view

I'm developing a game in Unity. I would like to give the player the possibility to enter Google Maps streetview mode  while playing and explore some places related the game, but i don't if this is possible. By streetview i mean pano mode, not map. Does anyone have experience about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28512

Looks like someone made a tool. I know you are probably looking for some source, but it is possible, and to get you started you could use a cubed map